# Should Volley onResponse() be handled in a background thread?

Tags: android, performance, android-volley

I'm using Volley for all my network related code. Since Volley does the actual networking part off the main UI thread I havent really thought much about it but I realize now that in a few instances I do some significant processing of the response data in `onResponse()`. It seems like this code does indeed run on the main thread. What's the best way to do this? Should I define a AsyncTask for that specific portion of the code or should I just put the entire network request in a AsyncTask despite Volley's threading mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest NOT to use AsyncTask as it has its own drawbacks in case activity is destroyed or recreated. And moreover if you are using Volley's queueing mechanism, this will just work as a add-on.

One solution I can think of is to use Loaders. Make the network call and process the response in *loadInBackground* method. And when onLoadFinished is called, you'll get the processed response.

Another solution (Not recommended and not so efficient) is to use a Service. You can make the network call from the Service and process the data and communicate back to the Activity.

Comment: Why would a AsyncTask be a bad idea? How is it tied to any activity?

Comment: @ardevd You can refer to this http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/